# PHP - Allow more than one response

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my head around the amazon api with PHP. Currently I have this code in the program from another coder:

```
        if ($pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability == 'Usually dispatched within 24 hours')
            $stock = ($pxml->Items->Item->OfferSummary->TotalNew > 0) ? '1' : '0';
        else
            $stock = 0;
```

How can I make it so instead of a response of `Usually dispatched within 24 hours` we also allow a response of `Usually ships in 1-2 business days` as well.

Do I need to use the `or` designator?

Comment: As in: `if ($pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability == 'Usually dispatched within 24 hours' || $pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability == 'Usually ships in 1-2 business days')`? Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm voting this down because the question basically contains the answer, you just needed the confidence to try it. You'll get much further if you experiment on your own, then ask here if your experiments lead to a dead end; then you can show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'd also suggest that this isn't the best code to read and copy from, as it has some rather bad coding style: e.g. if and else with no {}, the variable $stock being set to a string in one case, and an integer in the other (and quite possibly being used later as a boolean, given that it's only ever set to 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability ==
'Usually dispatched within 24 hours' ||
$pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability ==
'Usually ships in 1-2 business days'){
```

Use the [logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for "OR" ( `||` ) -- If you want to perform the same behavior for both "within 24 hours" and "in 1-2 business days". Otherwise,

```
 if ($pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability ==
 'Usually dispatched within 24 hours'){
     //do X
 }
 elseif($pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability ==
 'Usually ships in 1-2 business days'){ 
     //do Y
 }
```

Will allow you to do different things based on the different responses

Comment: You have an extra `(`

Answer (score 1):

Or... you actually refine your php so that it is easier to make sense of and edit in the future:

```
$val = $pxml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Availability; 
if ($val == 'Usually dispatched within 24 hours'){
     //do X ;
 }
 elseif($val == 'Usually ships in 1-2 business days'){ 
     //do Y ;
 }
```

This way, you can add as many elseif conditions as you would like, or change your XML value and not have to repeat the changes over and over. If it gets too big, make it a case.

Comment: Or if they're the same action, as implied by the question, `if ($val == 'Usually dispatched within 24 hours' || $val == 'Usually ships in 1-2 business days')`. But +1 for the very sensible use of an intermediate variable rather than repeating such a long expression.